# How do I show TFS work item in a dialog in an extension?

Tags: tfs

I'm using TFS 2018.

I created an extension that has a grid with tests for a release. Currently it will open the work item in a new page. I want the title to have a link that will open the work item in a dialog. The backlog page and some dashboard widgets have this functionality.

Do I use a dialog control or does the grid just need the correct structure and classes?